# How is this Jacobian matrix calculated?

Tags: calculus, matrices, machine-learning, jacobian

I'm going through the matrix calculus tutorial here [The Matrix Calculus You Need For Deep Learning](https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/) and I am puzzled by this equation here:

[image]

Assuming that:

[image]

I don't get why the partial derivatives of $x_i$ with respect to $x_j$ equals to $0$ when $j \neq i$. If we take the first horizontal vector of as an example, shouldn't the second element, partial derivative of $x_1$ with respect to $x_2$ return $3(x_1)^2$?

Comment: why are you assuming $f_1(\mathbf{x})=3x_1^2x_2$ and $f_2(\mathbf{x})=2x_1+x_2^8$? the place in the article where you found the first long equation is specifically computing the Jacobian for the identity function $f_i(\mathbf{x})=x_i$, not for an arbitrary function

Comment: I see. I thought so cause of this line "The Jacobian of the identity function $f(x) = x$ with $f_i(x) = x_i$ has n functions and each function has n parameters held in a single vector x." I thought the author was still referring to the $f(x)$ from the previous example.

Comment: ah, fair enough! :) as an exercise, it's worth computing the Jacobian of the function listed above; this will be a $2x2$ matrix

Comment: So then what is the purpose of demonstrating the Jacobian of the identity function? Is there a connection to the application of matrix  calculus in neural networks?

Comment: well, the identity function is one of the simplest toy examples to compute, so I think the author included that computation just to demonstrate what a sample Jacobian calculation looks like

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: my pleasure! happy it helped :)